# Replacing an IP address?

Tags: node.js

**What I want to know**

I would like to know how to *detect an IP address then replace it with another string*, maybe something like "censored" or "nah".

---

**Why?**

Mainly because I want to censore out an ip address if it is detected as one.

Comment: Do you want to censor *your* IP address?

Comment: No, any IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **String.prototype.replace()** and a **regular expression**:

> The replace() method returns a new string with some or all matches of a pattern replaced by a replacement. The pattern can be a string or a RegExp, and the replacement can be a string or a function to be called for each match.
>
> *Note: The original string will remain unchanged.*
>
> Syntax
>   **str.replace(regexp|substr, newSubstr|function)**

You have many sources if you need to understand better how to handle replace() method, here's one:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Just follow that tutorial (or any similar) to understand how to work with replace(), then go ahead reading here.

---

**REGEX**

Now that you know how to use regex to create overwritten strings in matched points, you need the proper regex to match your scenario.

A good starting point for an IP regex would be this simplified one:

```
\b(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b
```

it's pretty easy and usable too, but even if we correctly handle IP's syntax with this one, we would match any number from 0 to 999, so it could match inconsistent address (e.g. out-of-range IPs, like 192.168.1.999, would match).
This is a good starting point if you're not confident with regex by the way.

A more accurate, yet more difficult to understand regex, would be the following:

```
\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b
```

This fixes previous problems and acts fairly well.

Here's all that you need, and please notice that this answers many scenarios, just replace the regex with a proper one if you need to match something else.

Last but not least, just remember to **always double the backslash, as you need it to be parsed correctly in your Java code**, so last one would be

```
 \\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\b
```